# Batch file to create file structure according to another structure

Tags: file, batch-file, vbscript, structure

Alright to i need to make a script (VBS, Batch, whatever works) that will take an existing file structure, duplicate it and create specific subfolders in the new structure for each folder. Example

```
Current structure :
Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder 3
```

The script will take these and in another folder will recreate the following structure :

```
Folder 1
*-- Folder X
*-- Folder Y
*-- Folder Z
Folder 2
*-- Folder X
*-- Folder Y
*-- Folder Z
```

Comment: This question makes no sense. The starting and ending folder structures don't agree with the body of the question text. You say you are duplicating an existing structure, but your result lacks any such duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this powershell script should do what you want :

```
$source_dir="c:\temp\structure"
$destination="c:\desination"

$model=ls $source_dir -dir
$model |%{ 
    $name=$_.name
    new-item -itemType directory -path $destination\$name
    ("X","Y","Z")|% { new-item -itemType directory -path $destination\$name\$_}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    set "source=c:\source"
    set "target=c:\target"
    for /d %%f in ("%source%\*") do for %%t in ("X" "Y" "Z") do (
        echo md "%target%\%%~nxf\%%~t" 2>nul
    )
```

Directory creation is only echoed to console. If output is correct, remove `echo` command before `md`

Answer (score 0):

VBScript solution:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src = "C:\foo"
dst = "C:\bar"

newFolders = Array("X", "Y", "Z")

For Each sf In fso.GetFolder(src).SubFolders
  dir = fso.BuildPath(dst, sf.Name)
  fso.CreateFolder dir
  For n In newFolders
    fso.CreateFolder fso.BuildPath(dir, n)
  Next
Next
```